# coreos docker 1.7.1 -v file.txt:file.txt not updating

Tags: docker, coreos

I am using core os Stable 766.4.0 with docker 1.7.1.

When I run a container with -v file.txt:file.txt it does not update when I change the file on the host(coreos).

```
docker run \
--name proxy \
-v /user/whatever/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:rw \
-p 80:80 \
-d \
nginx
```

:rw not working
Any idea?

Comment: Can you specify the complete docker run command ?

Comment: docker run \
--name mynginx \
-v /user/whatever/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:rw \
-p 80:80 \
-d \
nginx